# PHP with ADODB execute call returns false

Tags: php, adodb-php

I use ADODB 5.21.2 with PHP 7.4. I am getting an error 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' when execute a query. My database is MySQL 5.7 and I am using the mysqli driver. This is failing on only one of my servers. The query works on 10's of other servers. Baffled. Any help will be appreciated. Calling the execute method to run an insert SQL.

```
$rs = $glb_dbconn->Execute($sql);
```

I was expecting a resultset to be returned. But, the execute is returing 'false'. I also tried running a select query that would actually return a result set. Even that failed with the same error.

Comment: Please review this https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/issues/388 . You need to close before make new query.

Comment: This issue was much upstream in the code. A valid query was returning a null instead of a resultset. It looks like a resultset was created but not returned for some reason. That had a downstream impact and was throwing this error. Changing the implementation resolved the problem for me.